# Create-react-app stuck on "found 0 vulnerabilities"

Tags: reactjs, npm

After running "create-react-app (app name)" , cmd stopped on "found 0 vulnerabilites" (excuse my english)
[image]
But sometimes the process stops here(waited for more than an hour):

[image]
I use npx create-react-app

Comment: Hi Dario Mitsev, can you add a screenshoot or write more details? thanks

Comment: I re-edited the question.Now you can see

Answer (score 1):

Use **npx**, it's the preferred way. first delete the global create-react-app:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then:

```
npx create-react-app my-app-name
```

Comment: I use npx every time